# What is the reasonable time interval to invalidate (refresh ) any cache?

Tags: postgresql, caching, ehcache, cache-invalidation

We decide to use cache (not decide specific cache) , but today came to know that we need to invalidate the cache data or refresh the cache data for every 2 minutes by connecting to datastore , but i am thinking that 2 min is  not feasible , because if you keep on refresh the cache data for every 2 min , then it is better to connect to the data store itself , so can anyone please suggest what is feasible time interval , we can set to invalidate the cache of old date and refresh the cache with data from data store ?

Note : we are using spring boot , postgres

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused about caching. If you cache the result of an operation (let say *X*) for two minutes, it means that everyone that repeat the operation in less than two minutes will have *X* as result, after the two minutes the cache is invalidated, and will be stored again *the next time* the operation is requested, so if nobody execute the operation for two hours it will be refreshed after two hours.

The time an item should be present in a cache depends on a lot of factors, there is no way to calculate an absolute feasible value for all cases.

- Which is the execution rate of the operation to cache?
- Does the result of the operation change fast? Are you caching something that change daily? hourly?
- Is it acceptable for who get the cached result to have an old version of the result, how old it can be?

I leave you with this quote (it is a must on this topic):

```
"There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: 
cache invalidation and naming things."

-- Phil Karlton
```